# Reference for a proof of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg Interpolation Inequality?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, sobolev-spaces

In the book *Linear and Quasi-linear Evolution Equations in Hilbert Spaces* by Cherrier and Milani, Theorem 1.5.2, we are given the following version of the GN interpolation inequality:

> Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^d$ be a bounded domain or all of $\Bbb R^d$. Let $m\in\Bbb N$, $p,r\in[1,\infty]$, and $u\in L^p(\Omega)\cap L^r(\Omega)$. Assume that $\partial_x^m u\in L^p(\Omega)$. Then for integer $0\le j\le m$ and $\theta\in \left[\frac{j}{m},1\right]$ (with the exception $\theta\ne 1$ when $m-j-\frac{d}{2}\in\Bbb N$), define $q$ by $$\frac{1}{q}=\frac{j}{d}+\theta\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{m}{d}\right)+(1-\theta)\frac{1}{r}.$$
>   Then, for any $\gamma\in\Bbb N^d$ with $|\gamma|=j$, $\partial_x^\gamma u\in L^q(\Omega)$ and we have the Gagliardo-Nirenberg Inequality $$\lVert\partial_x^\gamma u\rVert_{L^q}\le C\lVert\partial_x^m u\rVert_{L^p}^\theta\lVert u\rVert_{L^r}^{1-\theta}+C_1\lVert u\rVert_{L^s}$$ with finite $1\le s\le\max\{p,r\}$, $C$ and $C_1$ independent of $u$, $C$ independent of $\Omega$, and $C_1\xrightarrow{\operatorname{vol}(\Omega)\to\infty}0$.

Now, I am familiar with the inequality $$\lVert u\rVert_{L^{\frac{pd}{d-p}}(\Bbb R^d)}\le C_{d,p}\lVert\nabla u\rVert_{L^p(\Bbb R^d)}$$ and I'm told that this can be used to prove the more general Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality, but I don't see how this would be done.

Comment: To get started: Insert $u = v^\gamma$ for $\gamma > 1$ into the inequality you stated at the bottom (the case for $p=1$ there should be enough).

Comment: I know how to prove that inequality, but I don't see how to use it to derive the GN inequality.

Comment: That's okay, and what I wrote will (or may) help you see it..

Comment: But how do higher order derivatives come in

Comment: Higher derivatives come in by going down one derivative at a time. And always make sure your estimates are invariant under rescaling of both the function and space.